# How do I access/open a file in C# not using an absolute path?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, webforms

How do I access/open a file in C# not using an absolute path? The code below is not working.

```
string path =  Server.UrlEncode(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\css\\sample.css");
```

Comment: Not working how ? Server.UrlEncode is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decide what the relative path is relative to. It is common to use the BaseDirectory of the current application domain. Then use [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to get a full path:

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "some\\relative\\path.txt");
```

If this is an ASP .NET application, use [`Server.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx):

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/some/relative/path.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You want:

```
Server.MapPath("~/css/sample.css");
```

Comment: Assuming it's web development.